# How to send parameter when use redirect in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm supposed to use [`assign/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#assign/3) to send a message parameter like [1], when it comes to [redirect/2](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#redirect/2). Then I would like to get message parameter in index action.

```
def index(conn, %{"member_id" => member_id}) do
  # Show index page.
  message = conn.params[:message]
end

def create(conn, _params) do
  case Casher.create_members(members) do
    {:ok, members} ->
    conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Updated successfully.")
      |> assign(:message, message) #[1]
      |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index, member_id))
end
```

However it seems not to get parames in index action.
How should I get a extra params like message.
I don't like change parameters of index action.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`assign`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#assign/3) stores a value in the current request's connection struct. If you want to pass a value that should be read in the params of the redirected URL, you can pass it to the path generator function like this:

```
conn
  |> put_flash(:info, "Updated successfully.")
  |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index, member_id, message: message))
```

Comment: Should I change the lnterface parameter for def index(conn, %{"member_id" => member_id}) to def index(conn, _params})? Actually I am not sure how to receive parameters, just I know what I have to match the route.exx.

Comment: Yep you can do `def index(conn, %{"member_id" => member_id, "message" => message})` and now the message will be in `message`.

Comment: You can also use session (cookie storage), for example `Plug.Conn.put_session/3` and `Plug.Conn.get_session/2` to persist values between page loads/redirects.